# JComboBox event for when value is changed by choosing a new value from the drop-down lost

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a form type application in which the JComboBox I use to represent the title(Mr/Mrs/Ms/etc.) of the client. I want to trigger an event when the combo box has changed values due to the user clicking it to open the drop-down list, and then choosing a new value. I also have the client's names in a left panel. Clicking on a client's name will change the JComboBox to the value stored for that client, but I don't want to trigger the event when the value of combo box changes this way.

Both ActionListener and ItemChangeListener will trigger an event for both of these cases

The MousePressed method from the MouseListener will trigger the event for when the JComboBox is clicked, but not when the arrow next to the JComboBox is clicked[image]. Also, the MousePressed event will trigger regardless of whether or not the selected item in the combo box has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you trigger the event when the client's name changes remove the ItemChangeListener and add it back afterwards.  That way it will "skip" the notification

Comment: But when would I add it back, I thought about using a mouslistener to add it back, but clicking on the combo box arrow will not trigger it

Comment: you add it back right after you make the call to set the selectedItem on the JComboBox